# Member Valiable losing value on Tick (c++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently with a problem when trying to use tick to decide if I should or not do something based on a member variable boolean value.

Currently, I have a BindAction on my Player Character class, that when a given key is pressed, set the value of my member variable bTriggerPulled to True:

```
void AShooterCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
 {
     Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
     PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("HandleTrigger", IE_Pressed, this, &AShooterCharacter::PullTrigger);
 }
 
 void AShooterCharacter::PullTrigger()
 {
     if(GEngine != nullptr)
     {
         GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.f, FColor::Yellow, TEXT("Trigger is pressed"));
     }
 
     bTriggerPulled = true;
 }
```

In my Tick() function, I am checking bTriggerPulled to decide if I print or not something to Console Log:

```
void AShooterCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
 {
     Super::Tick(DeltaTime);
     
     if(bTriggerPulled)
     {
         UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Trigger"));    
     }
 }
```

The problem is that the bTriggerPulled variable always is set back to false when Tick() is called. I didn't make to fund a place where that value is being overwritten, and when inspecting that value searching for all its use, only these two place are showed.

I already erased the /Saved and /Binaries and /Intermediate folders to generate a new solution, but it didn't solve my problem.

I already checked all the usages of the member variable, but it's not being set to false anywhere.

[image]

Comment: You don't show how and where exactly the `bTriggerPulled` variable is declared and defined, but from the screenshot you show it seems `bTriggerPulled` is not initialized. Checking an uninitialized variable, as in `AShooterCharacter::Tick()`, is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I discover what was the problem, it's a silly one, but I will swallow my pride and share here anyways.

My class `AShooterCharacter` is inherited in a blueprint, and that blueprint is placed N times on my level, the enemies. When I was debugging, my IDE don't necessarily differed from the instances of that specific class. Because only one specific instance of `AShoterCharacter` (my player character) was responsible for changing the value of `bTriggerPulled`, when I was debugging `Tick()`, the value from another instance of my class was being displayed.

So yeah, a bit silly :)